# How to get if a Room is "available now" in Exchange with ews?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

How can i get whether a Room is available now?

I tried using [GetUserAvailabilityRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa563800(v=exchg.150).aspx) feature of EWS but i have to have another user and try matching their calendars and I dont want that.

How can I know if the Room is currently free?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I tried using GetUserAvailabilityRequest feature of EWS but i have to have another user and try matching their calendars and I dont want that.

That's not correct you can use GetUserAvailiblity just to query just the room mailbox that operation takes 1 or more mailboxes (I think you maybe confusing the suggested times feature).

In EWS you have two options for doing this you can either query the Room Mailbox's calendar directly eg https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495614(v=exchg.150).aspx or you use the GetUserAvailabilityRequest. If you only need to work this out for one mailbox I would suggest you just query the Room mailbox's calendar directly

Cheers
Glen

Comment: using the FindItem as you suggested, how do i "authenticate" as the room?

Comment: You shouldn't need to authenticate as the room as long as the user your running the code as has rights to the Room calendar in question all you need to do is use the Mailbox overload in the FolderId class see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086634/get-all-appointments-of-all-users-or-get-all-appointments-of-one-room . Otherwise look at EWS Impersonation